# creating a virtual microphone Ubuntu 16.04 and streaming audio into it from RTSP IP camera

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-streaming, audio-streaming, ip-camera

I need to create both virtual webcam and virtual microphone on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine for use in web application using WebRTC through my web browser.

I need to feed video and audio to these 2 virtual devices from an IP camera (RTSP stream). 
*Playing RTSP stream directly in VLC works fine with both video and audio.*

For this, I have created a /dev/video1 with video4linux2.
I am able to feed the IP camera to /dev/video1.

> ffmpeg -i rtsp://ip_address:554/streaming/channels/101/ -f v4l2
>   /dev/video1

If I look in VLC player, I can select /dev/video1 as a video device, but I have only "hw:0,0" as audio device, which is my in-built microphone.

**How to properly feed such RTSP stream to both virtual webcam and virtual microphone?**

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349689/create-virtual-microphone-and-output-sound-to-it

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of loopback audio driver.  If you want to do this at the Alsa level, you can lose the `snd-aloop` module.  https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-aloop#aloop_driver

If your intended destination supports Pulseaudio, you can add a null sink and use its monitor source to record from it.

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=video1
```

The monitor source is then named `video1.source`.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples

Then, you need to add an additional output from FFmpeg.  That might be as simple as adding something like `-f pulse "video1"` to the end of what you have now.

Comment: When I add `-f pulse "video1"`, the sound is played through my speakers directly (Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo) instead of the virtual microphone, maybe you have an idea why? Here is the command I used to play the sound through the ALSA virtual microphone: `ffmpeg -re -i webcam_record.mp4 -f v4l2 /dev/video0 -f alsa hw:1,1`. When I tested the result with VLC it did not work, I had to test with guvcview.